# Enforce tagging to azure databricks workspace

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

My aim is to enforce the developers to provide tags while they create clusters. I have added a policy in my ARM template which creates an azure workspace. It successfully completes the validation but fails to deploy.Sorry if my question is vague. Please help

```
{  
   "$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
   "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
"parameters":{  
  "workspaceName":{  
   "defaultValue":"xyxy",


   "type":"String",
     "metadata":{  
        "description":"The name of the Azure Databricks workspace to create."
     }
  },
  "subscriptionName":{  
     "allowedValues":[  
        "yy",
        "xx"
     ],
     "type":"String",
     "metadata":{  
        "description":"Specifies the subscription in which to create the workspace."
     }
  },
  "resourceGroup":{  
     "defaultValue":"abc",
     "allowedValues":[  
        "dd",
        "bb",
        "abc"
     ],
     "type":"String",
     "metadata":{  
        "description":"Resource group in which to create the workspace."
     }
  },
  "pricingTier":{  
     "defaultValue":"premium",
     "allowedValues":[  
        "standard",
        "premium"
     ],
     "type":"String",
     "metadata":{  
        "description":"The pricing tier of workspace."
     }
  },
  "location":{  
     "defaultValue":"east us",
     "type":"String",
     "metadata":{  
        "description":"Location for all resources."
     }
  }
   },
"variables":{  
  "managedResourceGroupName":"[concat('databricks-rg-', parameters('workspaceName'), '-', uniqueString(parameters('workspaceName'), resourceGroup().id))]"
   },
   "resources":[  
  {  
     "type":"Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces",
     "apiVersion":"2018-04-01",
     "name":"[parameters('workspaceName')]",
     "location":"[parameters('location')]",
     "sku":{  
        "name":"[parameters('pricingTier')]"
     },
     "properties":{  
        "displayName":"Enforce tag and its value",
        "policyType":"BuiltIn",
        "ManagedResourceGroupId":"[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', variables('managedResourceGroupName'))]",
        "description":"Enforces a required tag and its value.",
        "parameters":{  
           "tagName":{  
              "type":"String",
              "metadata":{  
                 "description":"Name of the tag, such as costCenter"
              }
           },
           "tagValue":{  
              "type":"String",
              "metadata":{  
                 "description":"Value of the tag, such as headquarter"
              }
           }
        },
        "policyRule":{  
           "if":{  
              "not":{  
                 "field":"[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                 "equals":"[parameters('tagValue')]"
              }
           },
           "then":{  
              "effect":"deny"
           }
        }
     },
     "outputs":{  
        "workspace":{  
           "type":"Object",
           "value":"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces', parameters('workspaceName')))]"
        }
     }
  }
   ]
}
```

Error: 
Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/04jdmgb-5642-8640-9a15-a0504248340f/resourceGroups/abc/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/test12' at line '73' and column '9'. 'The template parameter 'tagName' is not found. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#parameters for usage details.' Click here for details
Your deployment faile